# Need to remove {} object from array in Json

Tags: json, jolt

I have a json with empty object in a array. I want to remove them using Jolt spec.

**Input**:

```json
{
  "emails": [
    {
      "email": "abc@abc.com"
    },
    {},
    {},
    {
      "email": "abc@gmail.com"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Expected Output**:

```json
{
  "emails": [
    {
      "email": "abc@abc.com"
    },
    {
      "email": "abc@gmail.com"
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried below spec but seeing nulls in the outputs in place of empty object

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "emails": {
        "*": {
          "*": "&2.[&1].&"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**Current Output**:

```json
{
  "emails": [
    "abc@abc.com",
    null,
    null,
    "abc@gmail.com"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might start by getting an array, namely `email` within the first transformation while keeping the key names `emails` and `email` in order to transfer to the upcoming transformation such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": "&2.&"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": { "*": "&2[&].&1" }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the index of the objects starts would be 0,1 instead of 0,3 for the derived array `email` to be used within the second one.

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is :

[image]

Comment: Hi @Barbaros Ozhan, thank you for your solution
Above solution works if are more than one non empty objects in email array 
if there is only one email object then it returns null.

Comment: You're welcome @Anderson_502 , kindly you can paraphrase what you exactly mean as follow up through editing the question. You can keep the current one and add the new one as an extra case.